# Divisibility by 5 ,7 or not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a programme that calculates wheather the number is divisible by 5 ,7 or not. If the number is divisible by 5 or 7 the outpt will be the print statement otherwise the expect statement, but in my code if the number is not divisible by any of 5 or 7 then it stucks there.How to fix this? Here is the code:-

```
number = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
while True:
    try:
        if number % 5 == 0:
            print("divisible by 5")
            break
        if number % 7 == 0:
            print("divisible by 7")
            break

    except:
        print("number is not divisible by 5 or 7")
```

Comment: Why did you put a `while True:` loop there if you only want to check once? And when do you expect the `except:` block to ever be triggered?

Comment: you never ask for another number so it keeps checking the same one

Answer (score 1):

The except statement will never be triggered as you do not throw any errors.
You can just add the print statement at the bottom of the other if statements.

```
number = int(input("Enter an integer: "))

if number % 5 == 0:  print("divisible by 5")
elif number % 7 == 0: print("divisible by 7")
else: print("number is not divisible by 5 or 7")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming that you have added the while loop for repeated user input you can try something like this...

```
while True:
    number = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    try:
        if number % 5 == 0:
            print("divisible by 5")
            break
        elif number % 7 == 0:
            print("divisible by 7")
            break
        else:
            raise Exception
    except Exception as exception:
        print("number is not divisible by 5 or 7")
        continue
```

You can check this also...

```
number = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
print("divisible by ", number) if number % 5 == 0 or number % 7 == 0 else print("number is not divisible by 5 or 7")
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use exceptions for this though, they are intended for actual error handling. Even if you want to use them, a general exception is probably not the greatest choice as any exception in that try block will lead to that code. An if/elif/else would be way more appropriate here. Also in your second example, it will print the number you entered, not necessarily 5 or 7. So if I enter 14, it will print "divisible by 14".